# When A>B the output is always 1,but when A<B the answer is correct

Tags: python, for-loop

I already tried changing the values,changing the order,and using if statement,but it all results toa failure

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
list=(range(a,b))
t=1
for i in range(a,b):
t= t * i
print(t)
```

Comment: list is already reserved keyword in python which you declared as variable.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question so it's not clear what errors or other issues you're having. If you're calling `range(a, b)` with `a` greater than `b`, you're going to get an empty range object. Maybe that's your error? You haven't told us why you're doing that or what you want to do instead, so we can't really help you.

Comment: @Sunderam: `list` is not a keyword in Python, it's just the name of a builtin. It's allowed (though a bad idea) to use it for other variables. You won't get any errors from doing it directly, though it can cause subtle bugs later on, if you try to use the builtin and get the new value instead.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes this is right

Comment: Indentation level inside for loop is also not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

range() function create a sequence of numbers from A to B, so when A is lower than B your list will be empty and t will stay at 1

Answer (score 0):

A range takes two parameters, a start parameter and an end parameter

```
print(list(range(1,5)))
```

Output:
[1,2,3,4]

If the start is more than the end, it will result in an empty list
print(list(range(4,2)))
Output:
[]

However, range also takes a second parameter called step.
The step denotes how you want to get a new element in the range
If the step is negative, the range will decrease, printing the desired list

```
print(list(range(4,2, step=-1)))
```

Output:
[4,3]